# How could I add an element to specific index, then move all other elements up one

Tags: arrays, collections, element

I need to write an

```
public void add(int index, int element)
```

So if I had an array as such:

> ```
>      element: 9 1 2 3  
>      index:   0 1 2 3 4
> ```

And the parameters were add(1,8) to get:

> ```
>     element: 9 8 1 2 3 
>     index:   0 1 2 3 4
> ```

What's a good way to do this?

This is what I'm currently using:

```
for (int i = actualSize; i >= 0; i--)
       {
           if (i != index)
           {
               data[i] = data[i-1];
           }
           else if (i == index)
               data[i] = element;
       }
```

but if the call: add(1, 8) is made, I get the following output:

> ```
>      element: 9 8 1 2  
>      index:   0 1 2 3 4
> ```

Comment: Depending on the language you're using there are containers that will handle this for you under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a logical error in your function.  Do you want to move the elements that are below your insert index?  It looks like that's what you're doing.

What about the following for your loop:

```
// make sure that extra space for data[] is allocated

for (int i = maxIndexBeforeInsert; i >= insertAtThisIndex; i--)
{
    data[i+1] = data[i];
}

data[insertAtThisIndex] = element;
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be something like this:

```
for (int i = actualSize-1; i>0 && i>index; i--)
{
    data[i] = data[i-1];
}
data[index] = element;
```

But it depends on what an empty element means, like the one at the end of your initial array.

The trailing one will be overwritten, but, whatever they mean, those "nulls" in other positions will be moved like normal values.  That may or may not be what you need.